# Фильтр по текстовой переменной в DataFrame

Tags: python, dataframe

Есть небезызвестный набор по титанику. И необходимо отобрать по переменной Name (текст) только определенные значения. Например, только незамужних (т.е. где есть  miss). На выходе хотелось бы иметь dataframe с объектами, у которых присутствует слово miss в переменной Name

[image: титаник]

Comment: По возможности приведите формат ввода и хранения набора данных в программе. Есть много разных способов считать табличные данные, реализация вашей задачи различается в зависимости от этого.

Comment: @Timofey добавил представление данных. Думаю, тут нужно как с регулярными выражениями подходить?

Answer (score 1):

Можно использовать сроковый метод [pandas.Series.str.contains](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html):

```
df_miss = df.loc[df.Name.str.contains('miss', flags=re.IGNORECASE, regex=False)]
```

Как видно из параметров, можно задавать опции сравнения (игнорировать ли разницу в регистре, например) и даже можно использовать регулярные выражения.